# Как одному приложению передать другому данные через signal на golang?

Tags: golang

Есть два приложения.
Нужно, что б одно периодически проверяло-запущено ли другое(ну и передавало какие-то данные).
Как вариант думал веб сервер и через него общаться, но это громоздко только ради этого.
Слышал про сигналы. Как организовать общение через signal?

Comment: Через сигнал данные не передашь. Всё таки, IPC - это лупбэк, лучшего нет. Да, для того, что б послать сигнал, нужно знать PID процесса - опять проблема. Кроссплатформенно можно только `os.Kill` отправить, а это убийство.

Answer (score 1):

Зачем веб-сервер или RPC основынные на http (или включающие эту библиотеку в себя, она не хило весит) для простых задач? Основы IPC это общение через localhost, но протокол на любой вкус. В простейшем случае это TCP сервер и клиент. Да просто Read и Write - всё. Можно использовать хоть json, хоть [gob](https://godoc.org/encoding/gob). Всё что нужно, это объединить пару примеров из пакета [net](https://godoc.org/net) и gob. Вот и готовый RPC.

Но важно помнить о двух моментах:

1. Аутентификация
2. Шифрование

Аутентификация нужна чтоб сторонние запросы отклонялись. Иными словами, что б сервер знал что это его клиент.

Шифрование может и не нужно.

Варианты - это отдельная тема. Можно поискать легковесные библиотеки для этого, например [go-micro](https://github.com/micro/go-micro). Или писать свою реализацию.

А сигналы, это просто сигналы. С их помощью данные не передать. Плюс ко всему, нужно знать PID процесса (ещё одна проблема), работать с системно-зависимыми пакетами такими как `syscall` или `golang.org/x/sys/windows` (что усложняет переносимость на другие платформы). Если использовать пакет `os`, то на OS Windows послать можно только `os.Kill` - т.е. убить процесс.

---

#### Дополнение

Если есть возможность, то можно запустить второе приложение внутри первого используя [`os/exec`](https://godoc.org/os/exec). При этом смерть дочернего приложения можно запросто отследить. А передачу данных делать через Stdin/Stdout. В этом случае работа с сетью отпадает.